# Show how (0,(12)) and (1,(12)) are in different conjugacy classes.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

$S_3=${${(1),(12),(13),(23),(123),(132)}$}.

$\mathbb Z_2=${${0,1}$}.

$\mathbb Z_2$$\oplus$$S_3$={$(0,(1)),(0,(12)),(0,(13)),(0,(23)),(0,(123)),(0,(132)),(1,(1)),(1,(12)),(1,(13)),(1,(23)),(1,(123)),(1,(132))$}

$Z(\mathbb Z_2 \oplus S_3)$={$(0,(1)),(1,(1))$}

$C_{ \mathbb Z_
2\oplus  S_3}$($0,(12)$)={$(0,(1)),(0,(12)),(1,(1)),(1,(12))$}=$C_{ \mathbb Z_
2\oplus  S_3}$($1,(12)$)

Since (12) is present in both  ($0,(12)$) and ($1,(12)$) and both have same centralizers even then they are in diffent conjugacy classes .HOW?

I'm not getting how to show it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\mathbb Z_2$ is abelian. Thus conjugation can't change the first member of an element of $\mathbb Z_2\oplus S_3$.